# Page displays footer after loading

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I´m working on a bootstrap "one page" site for a client. First of all I´m a designer with limited programming skills, and now I´m struggling with a little issue that´s really annoying: when the page loads, it goes all the way down to the footer, instead of displaying the first section after the navbar (animated header image carousel). I´ve searched for similar questions but didn´t found any.

[You can check the code here](http://nhtest.esy.es/buro/index.html)

Please help with this problem, I´m sure it´s a simple thing that I´m overlooking, but again, I went through every line of code and didn´t found the cause.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the site sections don't have default height, so i suggest to give every parent div min height by css, for example :

```
.main_carousel
{
  min-height:500px
}
```